# What's the most efficient way to store a subset of column indices of big matrix and in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, openmp, bigdata

I am working with a very big matrix `X` (say, 1,000-by-1,000,000). My algorithm goes like following:

1. Scan the columns of `X` one by one, based on some filtering rules, to identify only a subset of columns that are needed. Denote the subset of indices of columns be `S`. Its size depends on the filter, so is unknown before computation and will change if the filtering rules are different.
2. Loop over `S`, do some computation with a column `x_i` if `i` is in `S`. This step needs to be parallelized with `openMP`.
3. Repeat 1 and 2 for 100 times with changed filtering rules, defined by a parameter.

I am wondering what the best way is to implement this procedure in C++. Here are two ways I can think of:

(a) Use a 0-1 array (with length 1,000,000) to indicate needed columns for Step 1 above; then in Step 2 loop over 1 to 1,000,000, use if-else to check indicator and do computation if indicator is 1 for that column;

(b) Use `std::vector` for `S` and `push_back` the column index if identified as needed; then only loop over `S`, each time extract column index from `S` and then do computation. (I thought about using this way, but it's said [`push_back` is expensive if just storing integers.](http://lemire.me/blog/2012/06/20/do-not-waste-time-with-stl-vectors/))

Since my algorithm is very time-consuming, I assume a little time saving in the basic step would mean a lot overall. So my question is, should I try (a) or (b) or other even better way for better performance (and for working with `openMP`)?

Any suggestions/comments for achieving better speedup are very appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems that "step #1 really does not matter much." (At the end of the day, you're going to wind up with: "a set of columns, however represented.")

To me, what's *really* going to matter is: "just what's gonna happen when you unleash *("parallelized ...")* step #2.

"An array of 'ones and zeros,'" however large, should be fairly simple for parallelization, while a more-'advanced' data structure might well, in *this* case, "just get in the way."

"One thousand mega-*bits,* these days?" Sure. Done. No problem. ("And if not, a simple array of bit-sets.") However-many simultaneously executing entities should be able to navigate such a data structure, in parallel, with a minimum of conflict . . . Therefore, to *my* gut, "big bit-sets win."

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Mike. But the issue of "big bit-sets" representation is that for parallelization in Step #2, the if-else check is needed for 1,000,000 times. How would that affect the performance?

Comment: Obviously, i am *guessing* here, but ... methinks ... "an array of millions-of-*bits,"* although perhaps 'wasteful' of *storage,* is trivially simple in *representation.* Many parallel processes should be able to pore over such a structure with nothing much more than "a simple mutex" to keep them apart. Computers are in the *business* of "doing things '(b|m)illions of times.'"THAT'S not exciting ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find `std::vector` easier to use.  Regarding `push_back`, the cost is when the vector reallocates (and maybe copies) the data.  To avoid that (if it matters), you could set `vector::capacity` to 1,000,000.  Your vector is then 8 MB, insignificant compared to your problem size.  It's only 1 order magnitude bigger than a bitmap would be, and a lot simpler to deal with: If we call your vector `S` and the nth interesting column `i`, then your column access is just `x[S[i]]`.

Comment: This. Reserve enough space for vector to not suffer from reallocations. You will have a smaller array and won't lose time doing ifs as with the other option. You can parallelise the computation as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks both. I thought about this too. But if, for example, 100,000 columns out of 1,000,000 are actually needed, then ``std::vector`` would have 900,000 elements not initialized. I cannot then directly loop over ``std::vector`` in step #2. Maybe I just count the # of needed columns and loop over that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on my gut feeling) I'd probably go for pushing back into a vector, but the answer is quite simple: Measure both methods (they are both trivial to implement). Most likely you won't see a noticeable difference.